# How can i filter a column in Django using .filter?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have the following line:

```
test = MyModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

The problem with this line is that it will retrieve the whole row. What if i want to retrieve the data from a certain column? For example, instead of the whole row, i'm trying to retrieve the column `email`

I tried this, but it's not working: `email = test.email`

Comment: use [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) or [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) to specify which columns to fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`.values_list('email', flat=True)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list), like:

```
test = MyModel.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('email', flat=True)
```

Then `test` is a `QuerySet` that wraps strings. But usually this is not good software design. Usually one retrieves and stores `User` objects, not column values. A model can add a lot of extra logic that prevents that certain values are stored, and it sometimes contains extra logic to validate, clean, etc.

If a `User` has a *single* `MyModel`, you can just use `.get(..)` instead, like:

```
the_email = MyModel.objects.get(user=user).email
```

or with `.values_list`:

```
the_email = MyModel.objects.values_list('email', flat=True).get(user=user)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm already using the Django user model. I'm not doing this to store data, my problem is that i basically have to add a div on my template containing the user's email, so that it looks like: 'Your email: .. ' (Give me 6 minutes to accept the answer)

Comment: @Jack022: can a `user` have *multiple* `MyModel`s?

Comment: @Jack022: note that a `.filter(..)` is a `QuerySet`: a collection of zero, one or more `MyModel`s, not a single `MyModel`.

Comment: Ok, i may have misunderstood this. Here is how i'm using it, you tell me if i'm doing that wrong. I need to add a div that should display some data stored in the db. So, for example, if the div shows the gender of the user, i will use .filter to retrieve the gender from the gender table, is that wrong? Or should i do it another way?

Comment: @Jack022: the idea of `.filter(..)` is that you get a *collection* of records, not a single record, so it can contain zero, one, or more `MyModel`s. It is not a single `MyModel` (well the *collection* can have a single item). So you probably want to use `.get(..)` (see edited answer).

Comment: Ok! I wanted to use filter() because it allows me to only show the data of THAT user, since it can filter by the user_id. I don't want to make a mistake and, for example, show other people's data on a user's template because i messed up the query in my view, since i'm handling sensitive data

Comment: @Jack022: but `.get(user=request.user)` does the same. In fact `.get(user=request.user)` is short for `.filter(user=request.user).get()`

Comment: Got it! Thank you @willem