# Limited some column in queryset django

Tags: django, django-views

I tried many ways but all failed when trying to get some special columns in model.

My code:

or I use defer

```
test_detail=testimport.objects.defer("so_hd","noi_dung")
```

or I use only

```
test_detail=testimport.objects.only("so_hd","noi_dung")
```

or even use filter and defer/only

```
test_detail=testimport.objects.filters().def("so_hd","noi_dung")
```

When I print `print(test_detail.values("ten_kh"))`, there are still results.

Because there are some columns I rarely use, so I want to save memory and improve speed if don't get there columns

Please help me

Comment: potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57645322/how-can-i-filter-a-column-in-django-using-filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to select specific columns of a table:

for this you need to use:

```
data = Model.objects.values('column_1', 'column_2')
```